# How do I make a many to many relationship with extra columns to same entity class using JPA and Hibernate (with Spring Boot)?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Suppose I had `Employee` entity class. Using `@ManyToMany` would make a simple relationship, but I want to make such relationship with an extra column. I created 2 classes, one acting as an entity and has data, including 2 ids (regular Employee and manager Employee), and the other as a composite primary key.
While I can now act as it is a relationship, there are no foreign keys. One way to put foreign keys in this new class is by adding `@OneToMany` relationships in the 2 classes related by this class, but I don't know if it is possible to do it in the case of the 2 classes being the same class.
Any ideas? My last resort is adding foreign keys manually, without Hibernate.

Comment: If you want extra columns in your relationship, use an extra entity with its role is to realize the `@ManyToMany` relationship. This entity gathers your 2 entities with a `@ManyToOne` for each entity implies in the relationship. You can add as extra columns as you want.

Comment: This is already explained. The question's purpose is to know how to do that for the same entity. In this extra class, I'm supposed to declare @ManyToOne with the 2 entity, but since the relationship is between 2 instances of the same entity, this isn't possible.

Comment: I see, I had the same issue one day and I didn't find a correct solution, I refactored the problem and defined another way to solve it.